# Using distinct()/group_by() in sqlalchemy to get latest record based for each "name" column

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

Current table:
table name: student

```
id | name | date
0  |Jones | Wed, 14 Nov 2018 18:00:00 GMT
1  |Jones | Wed, 14 Nov 2018 19:00:00 GMT
2  |Jones | Wed, 14 Nov 2018 20:00:00 GMT
3  |Su    | Wed, 14 Nov 2018 01:00:00 GMT
4  |Su    | Wed, 14 Nov 2018 02:00:00 GMT
5  |Su    | Wed, 14 Nov 2018 03:00:00 GMT
```

Accepted table *(return the latest record of each student)*:

```
id | name | date
2  |Jones | Wed, 14 Nov 2018 20:00:00 GMT
5  |Su    | Wed, 14 Nov 2018 03:00:00 GMT
```

Code used for the above:

```
queryModel2 = db.session.query(student)\
        .distinct(
            func.min(student.date)
        ).all()
```

which returns same thing with current table

2ed Applied
`queryModel2= db.session.query(student).group_by(student.name).all()`

which returns:

```
0  |Jones | Wed, 14 Nov 2018 18:00:00 GMT
3  |Su    | Wed, 14 Nov 2018 01:00:00 GMT
```

I also tried use oder by asc, but it still returns the same thing with 2ed apply

What should I add to get the latest record of each student?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? If PostgreSQL, you can use `DISTINCT ON` combined with `ORDER BY`. If some other DBMS, then for example a `LEFT JOIN` that picks the row that has no corresponding row with a higher date.

Comment: Yours doesn't look like a **SQL** question, more a question related with how to use `sqlalchemy`, I assume in [python]

Comment: I am using mysql, but I want to use sqlalchemy.session.query to get the expected result

Comment: `SELECT name, MAX(date) FROM student GROUP BY name`

Comment: I know how to use sql to solve this question, but I do not how to apply sqlalchemy here

Comment: Maybe this is the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66590362/flask-sqlalchemy-query-for-returning-newest-and-using-distinct-columns (especially if you also have other columns in your table and you want these as well - not just that timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good opportunity to use `rank` function:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

subquery = db.session.query(
    func.rank().over(
        order_by=student.date.desc(),
        partition_by=student.name
    ).label('rnk'),
    student
    ).subquery()

query = db.session.query(subquery.student)\
    .filter(subquery.c.rnk == 1)\
    .all()
```